# Restarting a JavaScript for loop with the value given at the end of the for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, code-injection

I am currently trying to create a happy number checker using a simple for-loop in javascript.

```
function check(num){
    var sNum = String(num);
    var digits = [];
    while (num !== 1){
        for (var i = 0; i < String(num).length; i++){
            digits.push(sNum.charAt(i));
            digits[i] = Number(digits[i] * digits[i]);          
        }
        num = eval(digits.join('+')) 
        return num;
    }
    alert(num);
}
check(1);
```

When `num` receives its value after exiting the loop, how would I re-inject the new value of `num` back into the for-loop to start the process over again with the new `num value`.  If this can be solved with the current for-loop being wrapped by another loop outside of it, how would the new value of `num` re-enter? Thank you all!

**Edit**
Here is the updated code where only the number 1 works.

Comment: Create a function out of it and call it again with the `num` as a parameter?

Comment: When doing that, would `return num;` be taken as the new value for the param?

Comment: Avoid using `eval` in general, there's almost always a better way to do it. Here's one: `function sum(numbers) { var result, i; result = 0; for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { result += numbers[i]; } return result; }`

Comment: If you don't need to support older browsers: `digits.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking for a happy number is a lot harder than that. You write a loop that executes until `num` becomes `1`. Well, for unhappy numbers, `num` will NEVER become 1.

Here is some better code:

```
function check(num) {
  var sNum,
      digits = [];
  var num;
  while (num !== 1) {
    // Add up all the digits
    sNum = num.toString();
    for (var i = 0; i < sNum.length; ++i) {
      digits.push((+sNum[i]) * (+sNum[i]));
    }
    num = eval(digits.join("+"));
    // If num is 4, then the number will NEVER be happy
    if (num === 4) return false;
    // We must reset digits
    digits = [];
  }
  return true;
}
```

This is sort of a hack. `4` isn't the only number that isn't happy, but all unhappy numbers will eventually go through the sequence `4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20`... (source: Wikipedia), so I check for `4` (although 20 or 16 would have done just as well).

Also, using `eval` is considered bad practice. Use a `sum` function instead like:

```
function sum(digits) {
  var s = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; ++i) s += digits[i];
  return s;
}
```

Then you can replace `eval(digits.join("+"))` with `sum(digits)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially call the function recursively if a condition is met. For example:

```
function check(num) {
    // your code, and then...
    if(/* whatever condition */) check(num);
}
```

To do this, you might need to remove the `return num` from your original code, or put it at the very end of your function if you still want too eventually return the number.

Comment: Thank you very much. As a kid new to development , this is invaluable, reusable knowledge for which I sincerely thank you. It's there a term for calling a function inside of itself like this?

Comment: Since if a number is not happy, it will end in the cycle `4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, ...`, wouldn't your code produce an infinite recursion?

Comment: Actually yes, this is just a test scenario for a later project, so calling maximum stack size in the console is what should be achieved for unhappy numbers.

Comment: @Oriol, it depends on the condition that he prescribes. I only used `num !== 1` as an example. He could instead check, for example, whether the number ends in 4, 16, or whatever, and then call the function recursively.

Comment: @Jking, the term for this is called "calling a function recursively".

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick:

```
function isHappy(num) {
    if(num === 1) return true;
    if(num === 4) return false;
    return isHappy((num + '').split('').reduce(function(prev, digit) {
        return prev + digit*digit;
    }, 0));
}
```

Explanation:

1. First, we check if the number is `1`, as a base case to detect happy numbers.
2. Now, we must have a base case to detect sad numbers.

   According to wikipedia, sad numbers end in the cycle `4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, ...`. So we can check, for example, `4`.

   You could also check them all: `~[4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20].indexOf(num)`.
3. Now we do a recursive call to check is the sum of the square of the digits is happy.

   To calculate that sum, we use:

   1. First convert `num`to string: `num + ''`
   2. Then [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it to an array of digits.
   3. Finally we [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) that array to the sum of squares.